# How to compare two timestamp values in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

[image][image]I need to compare two timestamp values one is retrieving from the database and the other is the constant date which is the default value.

```
 var userdate = doc.data().Subscriptionenddatefrombackend;// the value here I am getting is : 2020-03-02T09:49:05.000Z
 var settingdate = new Date('2019/03/04'); // the value here I am getting is : 2019-03-04T00:00:00.000Z

 if(settingdate < userdate){
    console.log("new user") // the code enters into this loop instead of else loop why?
 }
 else{
    console.log("old user") // should print this line
 }
```

Comment: Is `Subscriptionenddatefrombackend` a string by any chance?

Comment: So, what's not working there? both dates seem to be actual date objects...

Comment: @Jamiec - Datatype of " Subscriptionenddatefrombackend"  is timestamp.

Comment: `timestamp` isnt a datatype in javascript

Comment: It is the datatype in my backend(Firestore) and please go through the edited question.

Comment: first check your both date are instanceof Date specially first one

Answer (score 1):

You are doing a comparison operation on an object and a string.

`userdate` is a string, and `settingdate` is an object.

You should try creating a new Date object from the userdate string.

`let userdate = new Date( doc.data().Subscriptionenddatefrombackend )`

Comment: It's not working

Answer (score 0):

You can parse it to create an instance of Date and use the built-in comparators:
Convert userdate to a Date object also settingsdate is already a date object.

```
new Date(userdate) > settingsdate
new Date(userdate) < settingsdate
```

Comment: It is not working

Answer (score 0):

by using [Date.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) :

```js
var userdate = doc.data().Subscriptionenddatefrombackend;// the value here I am getting is : 2020-03-02T09:49:05.000Z
var settingdate = new Date('2019/03/04'); // the value here I am getting is : 2019-03-04T00:00:00.000Z

if(settingdate.getTime() < Date.parse(userdate)){
   console.log("new user") // the code enters into this loop instead of else loop why?
}
else{
   console.log("old user") // should print this line
}
```

Comment: No point in parsing `settingdate`. That's already a Date object.

Comment: @Cerbrus date parse return `A number representing the milliseconds elapsed since 1970` so we can compare two numbers; I'm not going compare two date object, here we are comparing two `number`

Comment: So use `.getTime()` for the existing date object.

Comment: @Cerbrus yeah, that makes sense; updated();